# Need help in using turtle module

Tags: turtle-graphics

So I'm writing a program using the turtle module. I have 2 questions:

1. I have 4 turtles. How can I make their names show up on the screen while drawing?
2. After I finish drawing, how can I exit one screen and open another within the same program?

Comment: i can't help you with this one sorry ;) but for the future: if you have two questions, please make two seperate posts and give them a searchable header text. this may help other people with the same problem.

Comment: You should also show, in your question, what you have done to try solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 4 turtles. How can I make their names show up on the screen
>   while drawing?

Sure, here's a crude example:

```
from random import choice
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

NAMES = ['Donnie', 'Raph', 'Mickey', 'Leo']

SPEEDS = ["slowest", "slow", "normal", "fast", "fastest"]

FONT = ("Arial", 12, "normal")

MAGNIFICATION = 5
STAMP_SIZE = 20
MAXIMUM_SPEED = 10
LINE_OFFSET = 50

screen = Screen()

WINDOW_WIDTH = screen.window_width()
START, FINISH = LINE_OFFSET - WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_WIDTH//2 - (LINE_OFFSET + MAXIMUM_SPEED)

turtles = {name: Turtle(shape='turtle') for name in NAMES}

for offset, turtle in enumerate(turtles.values(), start=-len(NAMES)//2):
    turtle.turtlesize(MAGNIFICATION)
    turtle.color("black", "white")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(START, offset * MAGNIFICATION * STAMP_SIZE)
    turtle.speed(choice(SPEEDS))
    turtle.write("", font=FONT)  # dummy write for 1st undo

winner = False

while not winner:
    for name, turtle in turtles.items():
        turtle.undo()  # unwrite name
        turtle.forward(turtle.speed() + 1)
        turtle.write(name, font=FONT)  # rewrite name
        if turtle.xcor() >= FINISH:
            winner = True
            break


screen.exitonclick()
```

To do better with respect to text centering and eliminating flicker, we would need one or more extra invisible turtles to just handle the text.  However, when the turtles turn, the text won't turn with them, it'll always be horizontal.

[image]